# Trying to open a word document from excel, performing a find&replace and then copying the result

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, vba

But this macro isn't executing the find and replace.

It does everything else...just not that.

```
Sub ImportSectHWord()
'It is better to always define constants, even though they will default to zero
' which just happens to be the desired value in this case
Const wdDoNotSaveChanges As Long = 0

Dim objWord As Object
    Set objWord = CreateObject("word.Application")
        objWord.Visible = True
Dim objDoc As Object
Dim wdFileName
wdFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & ActiveSheet.Name & ".docm"
Dim strSheetName As String
strSheetName = ActiveSheet.Name

objWord.Documents.Open (wdFileName) ', ReadOnly:=True

Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(wdFileName)

'objDoc.Documents.Open (wdFileName)

        With objDoc.Content.Find
            .text = "^p"
            .Replacement.text = "^v"
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

        End With
        Set wdApp = Nothing: Set wdDoc = Nothing


objWord.Selection.WholeStory
objWord.Selection.Copy
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(strSheetName).Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(strSheetName).Range("A1").Select
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Paste



ActiveCell.Copy     'clears the clipboard before closing word.
'objWord.Close                 'clears the clipboard before closing word.

objDoc.Close 'SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
objWord.Quit
```

WordTableFixer

End Sub

This is where I think my issue is:

```
With objDoc.Content.Find
            .text = "^p"
            .Replacement.text = "^v"
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

End With
```

Sorry this code is such a mess. I've been monkeying with it all morning.

The goal here is to open the target word file (named the same as the sheet in excel), perform two find/replace's to clean out all the bad line break, then to have it be pasted into excel. In excel a third find/replace (in excel) to re-establish the paragraphs.

If I just paste the text in as is, I get all sorts of bastardized cell merges and junk I don't want.

Thoughts?

Comment: Is your code opening the document twice?  To me it looks like the find and repalce is running on objDoc but then you copy and paste the content from objWord (which would be the original content) and not objDoc (which would have the new content).

Comment: It's a mess. I kludged together a couple of macros to get here - I need to refine it, but I'm still at a very elementary stage of my VB-ninja skills.